# How to use aws encryption sdk against localstack kms?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-kms, localstack

I would like to use the python aws encryption sdk to encrypt and decrypt text. I would like to test my code locally against an instance of kms provided by localstack. I have `localstack` running in a docker image. Below is some sample code. How does one point the `EncryptionSDKClient` to the kms instance at `localhost:4566`? Thank you.

```
import aws_encryption_sdk
import boto3

kms = boto3.client("kms", endpoint_url="http://localhost:4566")

kms.list_keys()
create_key_response = kms.create_key()
key_id = create_key_response["KeyMetadata"]["KeyId"]


client = aws_encryption_sdk.EncryptionSDKClient()
kms_key_provider = aws_encryption_sdk.StrictAwsKmsMasterKeyProvider(
    key_ids=[key_id],
)


my_plaintext = "password123"
my_ciphertext, encryptor_header = client.encrypt(
    source=my_plaintext, key_provider=kms_key_provider
)

decrypted_plaintext, decryptor_header = client.decrypt(
    source=my_ciphertext, key_provider=kms_key_provider
)
```